# Inserting subview over modal view on Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, view, modal-dialog

How can I programmatically get access to the size of the a view that is encapsulated within a modal view on the iPad?

I am presenting a modal view on the Ipad using the UIModalPresentationFormSheet enumeration, and at one point I would like to temporarily present an activity indicator view over the entire modal sheet until an action occurs.  The problem I am having is I am initializing this waiting indicator view with the frame of the view controller's view, and for whatever reason, that frame is always showing up as (0,0,320,460). While this is fine for the iPhone, on the iPad, the modal form sheet is obviously bigger than that, and so my activity indicator is only partly covering the screen. Any ideas on how to fill the modal form sheet?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try view.bounds instead of view.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to add the activity indicator your view controller's xib. I've done this before and it works out well for me.

1) Just add a view over the entire view in your xib.

2) Make the background color if black and about 20% opaque. That will give you a shadowy overlay.

3) On the third tab in Interface Builder, you can see the autosizing information. Turn on all of the struts and springs (make sure all 6 of the lines are turned red). That will ensure the view will resize to fill the entire popover no matter what size the popover becomes.

4) Add your activity indicator into that overlay view. On the 3rd tab, in the placement section, use those buttons to center it horizontally and vertically.

5) For the activity indicator, turn OFF all of the struts and springs. That means it won't resize, but it will float in the center of the view at all times.

6) Add an IBOutlet to the overlay view in your view controller and attach it in the xib.

7) Then when you've loaded whatever data you need and want to remove the activity indicator, either set the overlay view to hidden to remove it entirely from the popover's view.